# Munin not logging anything after initial setup

Tags: linux, performance, monitoring, munin

I have installed munin on a Redhat 5 instance as suggested here:

http://www.howtoforge.com/server_monitoring_monit_munin

There's a cron job that runs the daemon every 5 minutes. My munin.conf looks like this:

```
dbdir   /var/lib/munin
htmldir /var/www/vhosts/[myhost.net]/httpdocs/munin
logdir  /var/log/munin
rundir  /var/run/munin

graph_period minute

[localhost]
address 127.0.0.1
use_node_name yes
```

Munin did generate an index.html in my subdomain/munin directory. I can get to the web page which only contains the "localhost" link. My machine has 3 IP addresses.

Should each of the IP address and their plesk domains be configured in `munic.conf`? I'm a newbie to this, is there anything obvious I'm missing to get munin to log anything?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the munin user was not allowed to access the /httpdocs folder. Doing a chmod 755 on httpdocs solved the problem. And make sure that the monitoring folder is also writable.

To be sure, check your /var/log/munin/munin-html.log file to see if it could write graphs.